# Regex multi-line working in regexr but not PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a regex query working in regexr but it will not work for me in PowerShell. What am I doing wrong?

**regex**

```
(Host.*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*)+[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*))
```

**Data**

```
HostName: ComputerName
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 09:16:02
Step: 01
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 09:29:18
Step: 02
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 09:47:38
Step: 03
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 10:08:43
Step: 04
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 10:27:00
Step: 05
Date: 2018-12-21
Time: 10:45:14
Step: 06
Date: 2018-12-26
Time: 10:02:39
```

On match it captures the rest of the line and the next two lines. Since everything is in groups of 3 per entry in the log.

I pasted the working code in powershell and attempted the three ways.

```
$data | select-string -match "(Host.*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*)+[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*))"

$data -matches "(Host.*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*)+[\r\n]+([^\r\n]*))"
```

I've done research and the closest thing I can get is that windows doesn't play nice with `\r\n`.

I haven't found a solution yet.

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to replace `\r\n` with?

Comment: What is the output of `$data.GetType().FullName`?

Comment: Result of GetType is System.Object[]

Comment: Data Was Gathered via Get-Content

Comment: Keep in mind that if you use Get-Content without the -Raw switch you'll end up with an array of strings instead of a single string (with linebreaks)

Comment: do you just want the 1st 3 lines? that is all that regexr shows being captured. if so, there are simpler ways to grab lines 0-2 ...

Comment: `$data` -> `$data | Out-String`. Or read the file with `Get-Content -Raw` (requires PowerShell v3 or newer). All of your approaches check each individual line of `$data` separately, thus not finding a match. You need the entire content of the file as a single string for the match to work.

Comment: I am currently working on setting this up to get each step in to a variable. I will only have to change the starting match to get each one. Once they're in the variable I will query again based on each step to get Date and Time Seperately. Those will be used to set up a get-eventLog scenario and only return errors in between steps

Comment: I have it working. Thank you all for the help. @Ansgar you were correct. It wasn't all a string. Matches works on it and I can pull them with the $Matches[0] Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data isn't what you expect. `Get-Content` reads files into an array of lines and removes the line breaks from the end of each line. Both `Select-String` and `-match` check each line separately against the regular expression, but can't find a match, because each line contains only a fraction of what you want matched.

To fix the issue you need the entire content of the file as a single string.

```
$data = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | Out-String
```

On PowerShell v3 or newer you could also use

```
$data = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw
```